# C# converts T-SQL date datatype to DateTime datatype by default

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, datetime

When transfering a table from a database to a datagrid (WPF), the DATE datatype from T-SQL is converted to DateTime, but I don't want that. I want only the `.Date` part to show up in my datagrid.

Here's the piece of code in c#:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bibliotvguia.get_progtv();", con);

adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

dt = new DataTable();
adap.Fill(dt);
programs_datagrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

And the XAML piece of code:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" Name="programs_datagrid" Height="340"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns >
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Canal de TV" Binding="{Binding canal_media}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dia" Binding="{Binding dia_media}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hora" Binding="{Binding hora_media}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Produção Audiovisual" Binding="{Binding titulo}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

The `dia_media` column is the one that has a `DateTime` type.

Thanks for your help.

The best for you.

Comment: Instead of select *, select all the fields but the date one.  For that, use the convert function to put it into a string in the format you want.

Comment: [`DATE` column type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) is for datetimes. Why don't you want this? If you want to show only `.Date` property, then you can bound their `.Date` properties to your datagrid. Of you can use [`"d"` standart pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#ShortDate). What is `bibliotvguia.get_progtv()` for exactly by the way?

Comment: Given the time part is going to be zero, why do you care? Having it there is far less of an issue than storing dates as strings which is a baaaaaaaaaaaaad idea anytime.

Comment: You must show your XAML for better assistance.

Comment: Soner, the get_progtv() is an UDF to extract a table from my schema

Answer (score 4):

There is only the DateTime type in NET, so you can't really have a variable with only the Date part. This kind of problem should not be resolved changing the storage of your datetime values or inserting complicate SQL function to extract the value as string or to remove the time part.

It is only just a matter on how do you format your data for presentation.

I suppose that you need something like this in your XAML

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dia" Binding="{Binding dia_media, 
                                 StringFormat=dd MM yyyy}"/>
```

Comment: It worked but there's some aditional characters `()dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: Just change string format to dd-MM-yyyy then. You didn't specify the output format, so Steve's guess is as good as any.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a converter in your binding

XAML

```
       <Window.Resources>
         <locl:DateTimeConverter x:Key="converter"/>
       </Window.Resources>
     ...
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" 
                                    Binding="{ Binding DateProperty,
                                               Converter={ StaticResource converter}}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The converter class:

```
 public class DateTimeConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DateTime dateValue = (DateTime)value;

            return dateValue.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and the result :

[image]

I hope it helps

Comment: Wasn't me who marked you down, but converting dates to strings is the last thing you do to them. Any chance you might want to convert them back to a date is a potential bugfest.

Comment: I thought he just wanted to present the date in that format.  Steve's answer is better for the scenario you describe. What  I wanted to do is just offer an alternative   means to customize the way data can be presented using converters

Comment: I didn't figure you were going out of your way to lead the OP wrong mate, but have a think on this. Once you convert a date to a string, "This is not a date" is a valid entry in the "Date" column in the grid...